# Kivy Read-Only TextInput, but with ability to select all (ctrl+a)

Tags: python, kivy, textinput, selectall

How can I make a [TextInput](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html) in a python GUI app built with [kivy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kivy_(framework)) that's read-only, but where the user can still select all of the text with crtl+a?

Consider the following simplified example program with a TextInput containing over 9000 characters

```
import random

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout()

        # generate some random ASCII content
        textinput_contents = ''.join( [chr( random.randint(32,127) ) for i in range(0,9001)] )

        # add the textinput
        self.textinput1 = TextInput(
         text=textinput_contents,
         readonly=True
        )
        layout.add_widget(self.textinput1)

        return layout

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

I don't want the user to be able to edit the contents of the TextInput, but I do want them to be able to click around, select text, copy from it, etc. Unfortunaetly, in the above example, typing ctrl+a (for the `Select All` shortcut) does nothing.

However, if I omit the `readonly` attribute, then ctrl+a works again!

```
import random

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout()

        # generate some random ASCII content
        textinput_contents = ''.join( [chr( random.randint(32,127) ) for i in range(0,9001)] )

        # add the textinput
        self.textinput1 = TextInput(
         text=textinput_contents
        )
        layout.add_widget(self.textinput1)

        return layout

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

How can I make the kivy `TextInput` read-only without disabling Select-All (ctrl+a)?

Comment: Curiously, according to the code, select-all is one of the "actions that can be done in readonly" https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/88b34e190aa287f7a113ff7f2d503ebeb9b0e517/kivy/uix/textinput.py#L2972-L2975

Comment: This is a bug in Kivy. It was pointed-out last year https://github.com/kivy/kivy/pull/7449

Comment: This bug was fixed in Kivy since v2.1.0 (released 2022-03-06). See section "Core-widget" in release notes https://github.com/kivy/kivy/releases/tag/2.1.0